# Is the sequence a graphic sequence?

Tags: graph-theory, induction

Let $S=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ be a set of distinct integers.
Let $k$ is the least common multiple  of the numbers $\{a_1+1,\dots,a_n+1\}$.

Prove that the sequence that is take all the elements of $S$  $k$ times each is a graphic sequence. Trying to use the Erdos-Gallai  theorem but cant prove the second statement  with the inequality i try to use induction but i cannot do the second inductive step.

Definition :Graphic sequence if obeys at

[image]

Comment: What is definition of a "graphic sequence"? [It may be known but would be good to include it in question...] Also maybe give an example of such a sequence obtained from your conditions.

Comment: I have slightly edited it more. The sentence "the sequence that is take all the elements of SS kk times each is a graphic sequence" is slightly confusing but I presume you mean "$a_1,\dots,a_1,a_2,\dots,a_2,\dots$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need no induction for this.

By the definition of $k$ you can find $b_i$ such that $b_i(a_i+1)=k$ for all $i$.

Now just observe that the graph $b_1K_{a_1+1}+\ldots+b_nK_{a_n+1}$ has the desired degree sequence (this notation means: $b_1$ copies of $K_{a_1+1}$,
$b_2$  copies of $K_{a_2+1}$, etc, all disjoint).